# where to store data for tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, storage

I want to store some titles to be displayed in a tableview. Although I will not change this data frequently, I am planning on making updates on the it with after I post my app in the app store. Size of the data that I will be storing is not large, something like car manufacturers and models of each car manufacturer. My question is, where should I store this data? With core data, or with SQLite or just simply creating a JSON file inside the app and using it to populate the tableview?

Comment: Learn how to pass data to the app via webservice.

Comment: Hi, 
1)If it is permanent list then you try with "plist" property list. if you plan to change this in future via web-service, then please use Core Data.

Comment: Once you create a solution, please share your findings here in an Answer to we all can benefit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to update the data once in a while, you will need to be able to get the data from a remote source. It is important to keep the amount of data you download to a minimum to save battery. Add a date when the data was last updated. Store that date when you download the data. Set up a web service call to get the date and if the remote date is newer, download it else don't.

As I understand, you are going to replace all the data. For this, you should store the data as NSData (as recommended by Arun)

Answer (score 0):

1) If it is permanent list then you can use `plist` (property list).

2) If you plan to change data in future via web-service, then please use Core Data.

3) If you need to replace complete data from web-service and json result. Then (convert `JSON` to `NSData`) save to `NSFileManager`